# creating a HTML table with drill-down rows

Tags: jquery, html

Can someone please tell me how can I develop following type of HTML table.
All the categories and sub categories must come from db, dynamically and user will be able to tick boxes and submit the form.

Any sample website or any useful URL or coding much appreciated.

Link to Sample Table. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lfe4xvhwuoh31rv/form.png

Answer (score 1):

You can try jqGrid jquery pluggin.
Find more info here:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: Do you have any idea about [How to create jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991927/how-to-create-jquery-datatable-drill-down-rows) Thanks in advance...